# Getting "Property 'items' does not exist on type" Error but its defined in interface

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular13

My VS Code keeps giving me the error that `Property 'items' does not exist on type 'K2ItemList[]'.` But I have already defined it in the interface file and I have also doubled checked it and I dont see why am I getting this error.

What am I doing wrong here?

My `k2-itemlist.ts` interface file has this:

```
export interface K2Itemlist {
    site: Site;
    items: Item[];
}
export interface Site {
    url: string;
    name: string;
}
export interface Item {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    alias: string;
    link: string;
  }
```

My component file has this:

```
loadData() {
    this.jsonService.getItemLists()
      .subscribe(
        (data: K2Itemlist[]) => {
          if (data.items.length) { //  <== THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE
            this.itemlist = this.itemlist.concat(data);
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          this.errorMessage = error;
        }
      )
  }
```

Here is the `console.log(data);`:
[image]

Here is the Json Data:

```
{
  "site": {
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "name": "Example"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "2493",
      "title": "Introducing STEM",
      "alias": "introducing-stem",
      "link": "/articles/introducing-stem",
      "catid": "5",
      "introtext": "STEM refers to an integrated learning approach that introduces Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics through play-based activities.",
      "fulltext": "\r\n<p>Since the first few years are when the brain is developing most rapidly, it makes sense to incorporate STEM concepts, skills and dispositions in early childhood education.</p>",
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my `getItemLists()` service:

```
getItemLists(): Observable<K2Itemlist[]> {

       let _url:string = this.homeApi;

       return this.http.get<K2Itemlist[]>(_url)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

Comment: What does the console.log(data) show? And what does it show if you get it as `data:any`?

Comment: `data` is defined as a `K2Itemlist` *array* but you are trying to access it as if it was a single item. Hence the error, as the JS array type does not have an `items` property.

Comment: Hi @MishaMashina I will try the `data:any`. I have updated my question with console log.

Comment: Remove the brackets like `(data: K2Itemlist)`

Comment: Thank you @wlf I think you are right. I had also defined `itemlist:K2Itemlist[];` at the top which stored the data to that variable so it seems I may have to remove the brackets there too. I will try that now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. I changed the variable definition at the top and removed the brackets from it. But when I have it as `(data: K2Itemlist)` I get the error `Argument of type '(data: K2Itemlist) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: K2Itemlist[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'K2Itemlist[]' is missing the following properties from type 'K2Itemlist': site, items`. But if I change that to `data:any`, it seems to work.

Comment: Would be great if you can share the `getItemLists` method and also the JSON data.

Comment: Thank you @YongShun I have updated my question with my service and Json Data. After removing the square brackets, the error is gone, however I am still unable to define `(data: K2Itemlist)`. Only `(data: any)` seems to now show an error. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Sorry, My Mistake. It works now. Once I made the same edits to the service as well, it worked fine. My service was also having it as `Observable<K2Itemlist[]>`. Thank you so much much for all your assistance. Its a rookie mistake.